# Slicing pandas dtype object from end not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:[image]

where series_id is a dtype object. When I run:

```
df['dataType'] = df['series_id'].apply(lambda x: x[-1:])
```

Nothing happens, but when I run:

```
 df['dataType'] = df['series_id'].apply(lambda x: x[19:20])
```

It creates the correct dataType column.

Any ideas why I can't slice from the end of the object, but from the beginning it works?

Comment: Can you show what your expected results are?

Comment: yes, is was just supposed to be the very last character of series id, i.e 3, or whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and of course the answer was extra whitespace at the end,:

```
 df['dataType'] = df['series_id'].apply(lambda x: x.strip()[-1:])
```

.strip() takes care of it. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the last char of series_id, you can just convert it to str and take the last char from the string. Adding strip to make sure the trailing spaces are removed.

```
df['dataType'] = df.series_id.str.strip().str[-1]
```